# Whats the most Pythonic way to make the next n items in an array True, wherever there is a True value in the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of booleans

```
[False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False]
```

and wherever there is a True value, I want to make the next n elements of the array True. If in this case I chose n=2, this array would become

```
[False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

Whats the most pythonic way to do this, without using for loops?

Comment: Why do you not want to use for loops?

Comment: Do you have pandas? This is a simple rolling operation: `s.rolling(window=3).max().fillna(s).astype(bool)` strides of 3. You can also use numpy stride tricks if performance is important

Comment: Do you mean you have a *list* of `bool` objects? In which case, **why** do you want to avoid for-loops? **For loops are perfectly pythonic**

Comment: @ksbg I eneded up using a for loop, its just that I would like to learn different methods of doing the same problem and often for loops are much slower. Even if in this instance, it is overkill to not use.

Comment: @TomMcLean could you clarify what you really meant by `array` - did you mean to say `np.array` or `list` ? If it is `list` that you meant, then indeed using a list comprehension (i.e. implicit for loop) like I did on my answer below is probably the best way to go

Comment: @LeonardusChen my data format was originally a np.array as I had a time series of data  where I said array > value to find where the time series exceeded some value, which returned a NumPy array of boolean values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way would be using `np.convolve`:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.integers(0,4,20)<1
a
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
#        False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
#        False, False])
n = 3
np.convolve(a,np.ones(n+1,bool),"full")[:-n]
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
#        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
#        True,  True])
```

Comment: This is the way I was thinking of, thanks! I forget about convolving sometimes.

Comment: @TomMcLean if this solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer by clicking the big "check" button

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you mean `list` and not `array.array` or `numpy.ndarray`.

So for your example:

```
foo = [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False]
n = 2
```

The most pythonic way is - in my opinion - this one-liner list comprehension

```
[any(foo[max(0,i-n):i+1]) for i in range(len(foo))]

# [False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

With numpy, you can use stride tricks `as_strided`:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
 
s = np.array(
    [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False])
n = 2

s2 = s[:]
s2[n:] = as_strided(s, (len(s) - (n), n+1), s.strides * 2).max(axis=1)

print (s2)
# array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

This is pretty fast.

---

If you have pandas, this is a rolling operation:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False])
n = 2

s.rolling(window=n+1).max().fillna(s).astype(bool)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool
```